# Disable USB monitor when windows start

Tags: c#, windows

I need a method to disable USB monitor (secondary monitor) from displaying especially during the part when it hit login page.

I have already implemented codes to off the display using something like `changeDisplaySettingEX` which is already working fine.

It works in the way that when my application starts, then only the USB monitor will be on, when the application close, the USB monitor off too. (Under the monitors driver program it is shown as off if I switch it off)

So my problem is I happen to notice that when I shutdown my computer, this display auto power on again. Hence I'm guessing that when I start up my computer tomorrow, chances is this USB monitor will power on too, thereby showning the login page, which I do not want.

Anyone have any idea to counter this?
Was thinking of window service, but not sure will the service get activated 1st or the monitor get powered on first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, solved as I notice that the USB monitor have a service running.
So I only need to set the service start up to manual.
Start the service when program launch, shutdown service when program ends